# Почему жезл – процветший?

Tags: лексика, терминология

Из текста:

*А с другой стороны яслей, напротив Богородицы,  возвышается посланник Божий, Гавриил. Он сжимает в своей руке **процветший жезл**: сомнений – нет. У Девы родился сын.*

Почему жезл — не расцветший, а процветший? И почему этот символ стал  многозначным? В Интернете есть такая информация: *процветший* — по-славянски *прозябший*. Это действительно так?

https://pravoslavie.ru/103706.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, по аналогии с проросшим зерном *процветший* - тот, что неожиданно "процвёл".

В христианской экзегетике чудесно процветший Ааронов жезл считается символом Богородицы и в этом качестве часто встречается в иконографии, в миниатюрах, монументальной живописи, иконах (иконография Богородицы), являясь атрибутом как Аарона, так и Иосифа.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ааронов_жезл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB)
http://www.sedmitza.ru/lib/text/430985

«Процветший жезл», как следует из Ветхого Завета, является знаком данной от Бога духовной власти.
http://rusiz.ru/2019/01/18/zametki-o-simvolike-i-istorii-cerkovnoj-utvari-arxierejskij-posox

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пророс - это понятно,  потому что сквозь землю прошел. А здесь какое значение у приставки ПРО? А нельзя многозначность свести  к центральному значению? Жезл - это  символ избранности (неважно какой и кому данный)?

Comment: Нет, он не проходил сквозь землю. Вам нужно прочитать главу 17 Книги Чисел. Жезлы, в их числе Ааронов, были положены в скинию, и только Ааронов жезл расцвел.

"прозябе жeзлъ ааронь въ дому леvjине, и израсти ветвь, и процветоша цвети"

Процвел - устаревшая форма, в синодальном издании - "дал цвет"

Comment: Необязательно сквозь землю. Зерно может просто прорасти от влаги, находясь в посудине. *Пророс* - появился росток; *процвёл* - появились цветы. *Расцвёл* часто даётся в скобках к слову "процвёл". Но *расцвёл* - о эстетике, когда много цветов, а *процвёл* - чудесным образом появились цветы. Жезл не только символ избранности, а ещё и власти. Оказалось, что в словарях речь только о власти и почётном положении. Про избранность ничего не сказано. Избранность - как следствие, так как почётное положение и власть дают кому-то, избирая его.

Answer (score 3):

В Новом Завете, Послание к Евреям, 9:4

```
жeзлъ аароновъ прозябшій
```

Устаревшее значение слова "прозябать" - "прорастать, пускать ростки". На современный русский "прозябший" в данном контексте переводится как "процветший" или "расцветший". Дело в том, что в книге Чисел, 17:8 упоминается, что жезл Аарона не просто пророс, а на нем выросли цветы:

```
и процветоша цвети
```

Comment: А откуда  в слове прозябать значение прорастать? Это можно найти в словаре?

Comment: Конечно. У Даля, например: "ПРОЗЯБАТЬ ... Ныне бол. в знач. прорасти, пустить расток, мочку; семя прозябает, ожило, проросло, принялось, пустило корешек и стебелек".

Comment: Прочитала в словаре, что зябнуть, зябкий со значением мерзнуть - однокоренные слова, но это очень позднее значение, еще в начале 18 века в словаре его нет. А зябнути действительно прорастать, зуб - однокоренное слово.

Comment: У Козьмы Пруткова есть басня, основанная на омонимии этих слов: https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @Sharon Вот тут хорошая большая статья о [*прозябать*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/77), В. В. Виноградов. История слов, 2010.

Comment: Спасибо, прочту обязательно.